# Limits and intervals

Tags: limits

My book states that
'Set of all real numbers satisfying x>a is (a , infinity)'
Which means it doesent include infinity. Any explanation?
(Apologies for writing the word infinity instead of using its symbol)

Comment: "infinity" is not a [real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number).

Comment: But see [Extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Comment: Basically, when talking about real numbers, you can never include infinity, when talking about intervals. That is because, as Mauro said, it's not a real number. Rather, it's a concept.

Answer (score 0):

$(a, \infty)$ is an abbreviation for the set $\{x \in \mathbb R: x>a\}.$

Answer (score 0):

The limit is basically another way of saying "what y value is our function approaching as we get closer and closer to a particular x value." The limit doesn't care what happens at that x value or whether or not it's defined. It looks around and near it. Usually when we talk if a limit exists we mean that the limit is the same as we approach that x value from both the left and right side sides - unless we talk about one sides limits which is slightly different. Now, for infinity the limit doesn't exist because our function doesn't go to a specific y value as we approach that infinite asymptote or what have you. The y value keeps increasing or decreasing forever. Hope this helps.